# PHP conver string

Tags: php

Please help!

I have string with \x3c, \x3e ... chars. But when I do

```
$string = utf8_decode($string);
```

I must have < and >.

But this is not work! I don't understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of printing the string as it was before that function?

Comment: according to http://codepad.org/aVXqeh0n it works perfectly. please show as a var dump of your input.

Comment: Samuel Herzog, I know that when I write my sring: "this my string" it is work! But I get string from curl and it's not work!

Comment: We need more info to help. What do you mean with "Don't work". Do you get wrong charackters, do you get errors? What do you mean with "get string from curl"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$string = preg_replace("#(\\\x[0-9A-F]{2})#e", "chr(hexdec('\\1'))", $string);
```

Comment: Show me your code you are using now... I updated the code above